# PHP form not confirming errors on the form and not allowing some fields to be optional

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, post

I'm experiencing some issues with a php form i have inherited as part of a project.

The form has to be completed in its entirety to successfully submit, which it shouldn't do as there are optional fields here is no message to advise of the errors.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code snippet.

```
function validateForm()
        {
            global $error, $data, $errorBox, $successBox, $formShown;
            $formShown = true;
            $error = array();
            $data = array();
            $count = 0;

            $data = $_POST;
            $blocked = array('booooo');
            foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
            {
                for($i=0;$i<count($blocked);$i++)
                {
                    if(strlen(strstr($value,$blocked[$i]))>0)
                    {
                        $error[$key] = ' class="error"';
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
                if($value == "" || (strlen(trim($value)) == 0))
                {
                    if($key == "submit"){
                        }else{
                    $error[$key] = ' class="error"';
                    $count++;
                        }
                }
                if($key == "phone" && $value<20)
                {
                    $error[$key] = ' class="error"';
                    $count++;
                }
            } 
            // function to confirm form submission
            if($count>0)
            {
                $echo "Please enter all the areas highlighted in red"
            }
            else
            {
                $this->sendForm();
                $successBox = '<div class="successBox"><h3>Your e-mail has been sent.</h3></div>';
            }

        //Get the uploaded file information
                $name_of_uploaded_file =
                basename($_FILES['logo']['name']);

        //get the file extension of the file
                $type_of_uploaded_file =
                substr($name_of_uploaded_file,
                strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

                $size_of_uploaded_file =
                $_FILES["logo"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs

        //attachment settings
                $max_allowed_file_size = 1024; // size in KB
                $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp");

        //Validations
                if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size )
                {
                  $errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
                }

        //------ Validate the file extension -----
                $allowed_ext = false;
                for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
                {
                      if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
                  {
                    $allowed_ext = true;
                  }
                }

                if(!$allowed_ext)
                {
                  $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
                  " Only the following file types are supported:  ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
                }
        //copy the temporary uploaded file to uploads folder
                $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file; //NEED TO CREATE A FOLDER WITH 777 PERMISSIONS TO DROP THE FILE IN
                $tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

                if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
                {
                  if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
                  {
                    $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
                  }
                }

        }

        function sendForm()
        {
            global $data, $formShown;
            require_once('email.class.php');

            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

            $data['timeSent'] = date('l, jS F, Y \a\t H:i',time());

// Send email with enquiry details

            $contactemail = new Email();
            $contactemail->setTemplate("quickcontact");
            $contactemail->setTo('jonathan@email.com');  // or mike@email.com?
            $contactemail->setSubject("My enquiry");
            //$contactemail->setFrom($data['name'],$data['email']);
            $contactemail->setFrom("My Enquiry", "jonathan@email.com"); // double check
            $contactemail->sendEmail($data);
            //attach the file to the email
            //$contactemail->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);

            // Send email to the visitor to confirm the contact form they sent
            $contacteeemail = new Email();
            $contacteeemail->setTemplate("quickcontactee");
            $contacteeemail->setTo($data['email']);
            $contacteeemail->setSubject("My");
            $contacteeemail->setFrom("My", "jonathan@email.com"); // double check
            $contacteeemail->sendEmail($data);

            $this->unsetData();
            $formShown = false;
        }
```

Here's the HTML containing the optional fields.

```
<div class="row orange-underline">
            <div class="addressArea hidden">
            <div class="duplicateFree">
                <label>Free Standing Midwifery Unit:</label>
                    <input <?=$error["freeStandingUnit"]; ?> type="text" name="freeStandingUnit" id="freeStandingUnit" value="<?=$_POST['freeStandingUnit'] ?>"/>
                    <label>Free Standing Midwifery Address:</label>
                        <textarea <?=$error["freeStandingAddresses"]; ?> name="freeStandingAddresses" id="freeStandingAddresses" rows="0" cols="0" ><?=$_POST['freeStandingAddresses'] ?></textarea>
                    <label>Free Standing Midwifery Postcode:</label>
                    <input <?=$error["freeStandingPost"]; ?> type="text" name="freeStandingPost" id="freeStandingPost" value="<?=$_POST['freeStandingPost'] ?>"/>
                    <label>Distance To Main Site:</label>
                        <input <?=$error["freeMainSiteDistance"]; ?> type="text" name="freeMainSiteDistance" id="freeMainSiteDistance" value="<?=$_POST['freeMainSiteDistance'] ?>"/>
                    <label>Non-urgent Transfer Time:</label>
                        <input <?=$error["freeNonUrgentTransfer"]; ?> type="text" name="freeNonUrgentTransfer" id="freeNonUrgentTransfer" value="<?=$_POST['freeNonUrgentTransfer'] ?>"/>
                    <label>Blue Light Transfer Time:</label>
                        <input <?=$error["freeBlueLightTransfer"]; ?> type="text" name="freeBlueLightTransfer" id="freeBlueLightTransfer" value="<?=$_POST['freeBlueLightTransfer'] ?>"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="leftSpan"> <span><label>Any Alongside Midwifery Units:</label>
                                        <p>
                                            <select class="region_units">
                                                 <option value="select">Select</option>
                                    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i . ($i === 1 ? ' unit' : ' units'); ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                            </select>
                                       </p>
                                </span> </span>
                                </div>
                            <div class="row orange-underline">
            <div class="addressArea2 hidden">
            <div class="duplicate">
                                <label>Alongside Midwifery Unit:</label>
                                <input <?=$error["alongsideUnit"]; ?> type="text" name="alongsideUnit" id="alongsideUnit" value="<?=$_POST['alongsideUnit'] ?>"/>
                <label>Alongside Midwifery Address:</label>
                                        <textarea <?=$error["alongsideAddresses"]; ?> name="alongsideAddresses" id="alongsideAddresses" rows="0" cols="0" ><?=$_POST['alongsideAddresses'] ?></textarea>
                                    <label>Alongside Midwifery Postcode:</label>
                    <input <?=$error["alongsideUnitPost"]; ?> type="text" name="alongsideUnitPost" id="alongsideUnitPost" value="<?=$_POST['alongsideUnitPost'] ?>"/>
                <label>Distance To Main Site:</label>
                    <input <?=$error["alongsideMainSiteDistance"]; ?> type="text" name="alongsideMainSiteDistance" id="alongsideMainSiteDistance" value="<?=$_POST['alongsideMainSiteDistance'] ?>"/>
                <label>Non-urgent Transfer Time:</label>
                    <input <?=$error["alongsideNonUrgentTransfer"]; ?> type="text" name="alongsideNonUrgentTransfer" id="alongsideNonUrgentTransfer" value="<?=$_POST['alongsideNonUrgentTransfer'] ?>"/>
                <label>Blue Light Transfer Time:</label>
                    <input <?=$error["alongsideBlueLightTransfer"]; ?> type="text" name="alongsideBlueLightTransfer" id="alongsideBlueLightTransfer" value="<?=$_POST['alongsideBlueLightTransfer'] ?>"/>
                            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="leftSpan"> <span><label>Any Extra Addresses:</label>
                <p>
                                        <select class="extra_region_units">
                                          <option value="select">Select</option>
                                                <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i . ($i === 1 ? ' unit' : ' units'); ?></option>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </p>
                                </span> </span>
            </div>
            <div class="row orange-underline">
            <div class="addressArea3 hidden">
            <div class="duplicateExtra">
                                <label>Extra Unit:</label>
                <input <?=$error["extraUnit"]; ?> type="text" name="extraUnit" id="extraUnit" value="<?=$_POST['extraUnit'] ?>"/>
                                <label>Extra Unit Address:</label>
                <textarea <?=$error["extraAddresses"]; ?> name="extraAddresses" id="extraAddresses" rows="0" cols="0" ><?=$_POST['extraAddresses'] ?></textarea>
                                <label>Extra Unit Postcode:</label>
                                    <input <?=$error["extraUnitPost"]; ?> type="text" name="extraUnitPost" id="extraUnitPost" value="<?=$_POST['extraUnitPost'] ?>"/>
                                <label>Distance To Main Site:</label>
                <input <?=$error["extraMainSiteDistance"]; ?> type="text" name="extraMainSiteDistance" id="extraMainSiteDistance" value="<?=$_POST['extraMainSiteDistance'] ?>"/>
                                <label>Non-urgent Transfer Time:</label>
                <input <?=$error["extraNonUrgentTransfer"]; ?> type="text" name="extraNonUrgentTransfer" id="extraNonUrgentTransfer" value="<?=$_POST['extraNonUrgentTransfer'] ?>"/>
                                <label>Blue Light Transfer Time:</label>
                <input <?=$error["extraBlueLightTransfer"]; ?> type="text" name="extraBlueLightTransfer" id="extraBlueLightTransfer" value="<?=$_POST['extraBlueLightTransfer'] ?>"/>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You should post only the relevant code.

Comment: thank you, will do just that next time - i thought the additional code would help with context to the issue.

Comment: @i76970 in reference to posting relevant code, update your question and edit it to remove excess codeblocks. It makes debugging easier.

Comment: Thanks @martin i've removed the html code as the errors are within the php code i'm sure.

Comment: @i76970 add a `var_dump($data)` on the line before your sending of the email. Also, have you checked your PHP error log for errors?

Comment: thanks @Martin .. the error log doesn't display any errors other than ones i've caused to happen for testing purposes. I've updated the code to include the email class and just after the '//send email with enquiry details' comment, have added  the var_dump($data) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `'` which could cause an issue in your PHP code.

Replace this:

`$successBox = <div class="successBox"><h3>E-Mail Sent.</h3></div>';`

With this:

`$successBox = '<div class="successBox"><h3>E-Mail Sent.</h3></div>';`

Comment: Ahh, my bad for removing it during editing when pasting the code here. It was present in the code on my server. thanks!

Comment: does this solve your question, @i76970 ? If not, can you put up your email class, you have a comment in your code that implies you're using PHPMailer? If you are, you do not need header data.

Comment: nope, doesn't appear to have solved the issue. it doesn't appear that PHPMailer is in use either, if it is, i don't know where/how it is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Error in your code

```
$this->sendForm();
$successBox = <div class="successBox"><h3>E-Mail Sent.</h3></div>';
```

Single quote is missing it should be like this

```
$this->sendForm();
$successBox = '<div class="successBox"><h3>E-Mail Sent.</h3></div>';
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the code on the server is correct, it's my edit that's done it - i'll fix that now.